# calculate percentages with postgresql join queries

Tags: percentage, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to calculate percentages by joining 3 tables data to get the percentages of positive_count, negative_count, neutral_count of each user's tweets. I have succeeded in getting positive, negative and neutral counts, but failing to get the same as percentages instead of counts. Here is the query to get counts:

```
SELECT 
   t1.u_id,count() as total_tweets_count , 
   (
     SELECT count() from t1,t2,t3 c 
      WHERE 
            t1.u_id='18839785' AND 
            t1.u_id=t2.u_id AND 
            t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id AND 
            t3.sentiment='Positive'
   ) as pos_count , 
   (
    SELECT count() from t1,t2,t3
     WHERE
           t1.u_id='18839785' AND 
           t1.u_id=t2.u_id AND 
           t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id AND
           t3.sentiment='Negative'
   ) as neg_count , 
   (
    SELECT count() from t1,t2,t3
     WHERE
           t1.u_id='18839785' AND
           t1.u_id=t2.u_id AND
           t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id AND
           t3.sentiment='Neutral'
   ) as neu_count
 FROM t1,t2,t3 
WHERE
      t1.u_id='18839785' AND
      t1.u_id=t2.u_id AND
      t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id
```

GROUP BY t1.u_id;

```
**OUTPUT:**  

u_id | total_tweets_count | pos_count | neg_count | neu_count 
-----------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+------- 
18839785|         88 |        38 |        25 |        25
(1 row)
```

Now I want the same in percentages instead of counts. I have written the query in the following way but failed.

```
SELECT 
       total_tweets_count,pos_count,
       round((pos_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS pos_per,neg_count,
       round((neg_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS neg_per,
       neu_count, round((neu_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS neu_per 
 FROM (
       SELECT
             count(*) as total_tweets_count,
             count(
                   a.u_id='18839785' AND
                   a.u_id=b.u_id AND
                   b.ts_id=c.ts_id AND
                   c.sentiment='Positive'
                  ) AS pos_count,
             count(
                   a.u_id='18839785' AND
                   a.u_id=b.u_id AND
                   b.ts_id=c.ts_id AND 
                   c.sentiment='Negative'
                  ) AS neg_count,
             count(
                   a.u_id='18839785' AND
                   a.u_id=b.u_id AND
                   b.ts_id=c.ts_id AND
                   c.sentiment='Neutral') AS neu_count
         FROM t1,t2, t3
        WHERE 
              a.u_id='18839785' AND 
              a.u_id=b.u_id AND
              b.ts_id=c.ts_id 
     GROUP BY a.u_id
    ) sub;
```

Can anyone help me out in achieving as percentages for each user data as below?

```
u_id | total_tweets_count | pos_count | neg_count | neu_count 
------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----
18839785|      88 |        43.18 |        28.4 |        28.4
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are looking for.

For starters, you can simplify your query by using conditional aggregation instead of three scalar subqueries (which btw. do not need to repeat the where condition on `a.u_id`)

You state you want to "count for all users", so you need to remove the WHERE clause in the main query. The simplification also gets rid of the repeated WHERE condition.

```
select u_id, 
       total_tweets_count, 
       pos_count,
       round((pos_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS pos_per,
       neg_count,
       round((neg_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS neg_per,
       neu_cont,
       round((neu_count * 100.0) / total_tweets_count, 2) AS neu_per
from (
  SELECT 
     t1.u_id,
     count(*) as total_tweets_count, 
     count(case when t3.sentiment='Positive' then 1 end) as pos_count, 
     count(case when t3.sentiment='Negative' then 1 end) as neg_count, 
     count(case when t3.sentiment='Neutral' then 1 end) as neu_count 
  FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON t1.u_id=t2.u_id 
    JOIN t3 t2.ts_id=t3.ts_id
  -- no WHERE condition on the u_id here
  GROUP BY t1.u_id
) t
```

Note that I replaced the outdated, ancient and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause with "modern" explicit JOIN operators

With a more up-do-date Postgres version, the expression `count(case when t3.sentiment='Positive' then 1 end) as pos_count` can also be re-written to:

```
count(*) filter (where t3.sentiment='Positive') as pos_count
```

which is a bit more readable (and understandable I think).

---

In your query you can achieve the repetition of the global WHERE condition on the u_id by using a co-related subquery, e.g.:

```
(
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM t1 inner_t1 --<< use different aliases than in the outer query
    JOIN t2 inner_t2 ON inner_t2.u_id = inner_t1.u_id
    JOIN t3 inner_t3 ON inner_t3.ts_id = inner_t2.ts_id
  -- referencing the outer t1 removes the need to repeat the hardcoded ID
  WHERE innter_t1.u_id = t1.u_id 
) as pos_count
```

The repetition of the table `t1` isn't necessary either, so the above could be re-written to:

```
(
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM t2 inner_t2 
    JOIN t3 inner_t3 ON inner_t3.ts_id = inner_t2.ts_id
  WHERE inner_t2.u_id = t1.u_id --<< this references the outer t1 table
) as pos_count
```

But the version with conditional aggregation will still be a **lot** faster than using three scalar sub-queries (even if you remove the unnecessary repetition of the `t1` table).

Comment: thank you for your response. It worked to my requirement.